# Como hacer que funcione el salto de linea en <p> de texto con mas de un renglon

Tags: javascript, html, salto-de-linea

Tengo este texto:

> Quibusdam distinctio temporibus ut porro temporibus.
>
> Quibusdam distinctio temporibus ut porro temporibus.

Pero en el `<p>` sale asi:

**Quibusdam distinctio temporibus ut porro temporibus. Quibusdam distinctio temporibus ut porro temporibus.**

Como hago que funcione el salto de linea?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes Intentar con lo siguiente:

```html
<p>Quibusdam distinctio temporibus ut porro temporibus. <br> 
Quibusdam distinctio temporibus ut porro temporibus.</p>
```

Se agrego la etiqueta `<br>` para hacer el salto de linea.

Espero te sirva!

Comment: Gracias Jaime por la corrección! :D

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione.

Usando este código:

```
const textArray = text.split('\n')

textArray.map(item => {
        return <p key={item}>{item}</p>
})
```

Comment: Lo olvidaste? Y ya lo incluíste en la descripción? Ya agregaste los tags necesarios? Ya lograste que esta pregunta y respuesta sean útiles para otros usuarios quienes quizás tengan el mismo problema?

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción es usar la etiqueta html `<pre></pre>`.

```
<pre>texto en la fila 1
     texto en la fila 2</pre>
```

Todo lo que coloques entre estas etiquetas aparecerá tal cual está escrito con los saltos de linea y espacios....